# Looking to Count the Number to Times a Saleforce Campaign Member Enters a Journey in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

Developing a journey in Marketing Cloud that will send Salesforce Campaign members with a specific status a email reminder. I'd like to somehow count the number of entries so that I can cap the number of reentries to this Journey.

I'd then like to leverage that count to send a task an account rep to follow up with that account. The tricky bit here is there would be multiple contacts at an account and Id like to only send a rep one task for the account, not one for every contact. Also Id like the count to be a combination of the entries of all the contacts for that account.

Comment: You can achieve that by using SQL to combine data from the JourneyActivity data view with data from your synched Salesforce DEs and then using either JB or a script activity in Automation Studio to create a task

Comment: Thanks,
couple of followups. To identify the specific journey I want to track will I also need to use the _Journey view? Or can I track back to a specific journey using just _JourneyActivity?

Im hoping to use the SF object of (Campaign) to kick off the journey, because of this I don't have a SF DE to merge to. How do I overcome this?

Comment: Take a look at the data views documentation to check what you will need. Every journey has it’s own DE, even if it’s triggered by a SF campaign. Look at the data structure you have and figure out how it all connects.

Comment: Ahhh thanks @zuzannamj that was very helpful. I did indeed find a DE was generated for Journey. If in the future anyone uses this thread its located Top level Data Extensions folder and has the same name as the first name you gave your journey. It looks like if you change the journey name the DE name does not replicate it.